# Which RoR template engine is similar to the Razor template engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got really used to developing views in MVC4 using Razor. But I have to do a project in RoR and I'm pretty new to the whole Rails environment. I like Razor because it frees me from the <% business.

Can someone suggest a close cousin of Razor for Ruby?

Comment: I think haml might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The templating engine landscape in RoR is much wider than the one in asp.net.

I use Slim : http://slim-lang.com/ very similar to haml too.

Comment: I've heard of Slim before. It's pretty new isn't it?

Comment: pretty new, according to Github it started on September 13, 2010 : https://github.com/stonean/slim/commit/ef68004446c7c78817e7c39bc6447d494506fc78

Comment: This doesn't look anything like Razor?

Comment: I really don't understand how this is a good answer. Slim looks nothing like razor; Sterphane doesn't even attempt to answer the question asked, instead just informing us of how RoR has a wider landscape and giving his personal choice.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no syntax equivalent to razor in RoR. 
Arman specified why he likes Razor (i.e.: "I like Razor because it frees me from the <% business"). Slim achieves the same, and is also the reason I chose it. 
Feel free to suggest other options.

Answer (score 1):

I only know of 3 options.  As far as I know, there is no Rails templating engine that's exactly like Razor:

- ERB is probably most similar to Razor
- Haml uses slightly less verbose syntax and converts it into HTML. (No need to worry about typing div close tags 2 million times. Hurray!)
- I prefer SLIM.  It's like Haml but better because it has fewer characters and less weirdness (no need to type "%" before every line)