# Razor-like syntax in ruby-on-rails view

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asp.net-mvc, ruby-on-rails-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which RoR template engine is similar to the Razor template engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061785/which-ror-template-engine-is-similar-to-the-razor-template-engine)

[asp.net mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc) did a great job on mimiking Rails. 
i know that in rails if you want to add inline code into the view it has to be inside `<% %>` syntax.
in asp.net mvc it also exists but they added another option for syntax engine called [**Razor**](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx).
does anyone knows if there is a razor-like equivalent in rails (or any other way to render inline code in the view except of the standard `<% %>` way)? 
**EDIT**- i also know about **[Haml](http://haml.info/)** and i think it's not as elegant as i need it to be since it's a new way to write html tags. i prefer to stick with the standards and just have a nice way to put inline code.
thank in advance :)

Comment: i don't think they were mimikiing rails?! it's an implementation of a pattern they both share... there were mvc frameworks about long before rails came on the scene.

Comment: just look on the mvc partial/yields/name conventions and much more and you see it's the same as rails

Comment: It's a blatant copy. Having been working with asp .net mvc since 2008 and learning rails now - it's obvious... Though Razor is the best template syntax, I would love to take this to rails.

Comment: @sagivo since the answer I gave is misleading the people who are coming for a solution for ruby-on-rails, it would be helpful to others if you could remove the marked as answer so that I could delete it. Thanks